# How to customize python PyQt5 QWebEngineView context menu?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I am a beginner and need help to be an expert.
Its been a month, since I am working with PyQt5 QWebEngineView library

This is my code

```
# importing required libraries 
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *
import os 
import sys 

class MainWindow(QMainWindow): 

    # constructor 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 

        self.browser = QWebEngineView() 
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://google.com")) 
        self.browser.urlChanged.connect(self.update_urlbar) 
        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.update_title) 
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser) 
        self.status = QStatusBar() 
        self.setStatusBar(self.status) 
        navtb = QToolBar("Navigation") 
        self.addToolBar(navtb) 
        back_btn = QAction("Back", self) 
        back_btn.setStatusTip("Back to previous page") 
        back_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.back) 
        navtb.addAction(back_btn) 
        next_btn = QAction("Forward", self) 
        next_btn.setStatusTip("Forward to next page") 
        next_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.forward) 
        navtb.addAction(next_btn) 
        reload_btn = QAction("Reload", self) 
        reload_btn.setStatusTip("Reload page") 
        reload_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.reload) 
        navtb.addAction(reload_btn) 
        home_btn = QAction("Home", self) 
        home_btn.setStatusTip("Go home") 
        home_btn.triggered.connect(self.navigate_home) 
        navtb.addAction(home_btn) 

        navtb.addSeparator() 
        self.urlbar = QLineEdit() 
        self.urlbar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to_url) 

        navtb.addWidget(self.urlbar) 
        stop_btn = QAction("Stop", self) 
        stop_btn.setStatusTip("Stop loading current page") 

        stop_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.stop) 
        navtb.addAction(stop_btn) 
        self.show()
        
    def update_title(self): 
        title = self.browser.page().title() 
        self.setWindowTitle("% s - My New Browser" % title)
        
    def navigate_home(self): 
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.google.com")) 

    def navigate_to_url(self): 
        q = QUrl(self.urlbar.text()) 
        if q.scheme() == "": 
            q.setScheme("http") 
        self.browser.setUrl(q) 

    def update_urlbar(self, q): 
        self.urlbar.setText(q.toString()) 
        self.urlbar.setCursorPosition(0) 

app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
app.setApplicationName("My New Browser")  
window = MainWindow() 
app.exec_()
```

I don't have any issues in the code but I want to customize the context menu which appears when we right-clink in a page, I want to change its background color, and add a label with an icon on top, also I want to change the font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better solution is to subclass the web view and override `contextMenuEvent`.
If you also want to customize the colors of the menu, you should set the stylesheet on the browser, using the appropriate selectors.

```
class Browser(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            QMenu {
                background: lightBlue;
                color: orange;
            }
            QMenu::item:selected {
                background: lightGray;
            }
        ''')

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        self.menu = self.page().createStandardContextMenu()
        self.menu.addAction('My action')
        self.menu.popup(event.globalPos())

class MainWindow(QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 

        self.browser = Browser()
        # ...
```

Note: For various reasons (probably related to the complex architecture behind the web view), using `menu.exec_()` might lead to consolle warnings and painting artifacts, so using `popup()` is better; setting the menu as an instance attribute is mandatory, otherwise the menu would be garbage collected right after popup (which is *not* blocking).

Comment: Thanks for your response it was very helpful. But cant I remove the default fuctions(like save page)?

Comment: If you want to use only your own actions, then just create your own QMenu in `contextMenuEvent()` instead of using the default one. That's exactly the same as any other QWidget.